# Inserting "null" when no RadioButtons are selected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have CheckBoxes on my website which, when checked, are being stored into the database in the following way:

```
Cust.IsCust = Convert.ToInt16(cb_IsCust.Checked ? 0 : 1);
```

Now instead of checkbox I am changing it to radiobuttons with "yes/no" option. How can I insert these options in the database with 1 for yes and 0 for no. If there is nothing checked I need to insert null (management requirement).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can find the solution somewhere out there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

if you're inserting into the database right away, use a string:

```
string IsCust;
......
Cust.IsCust = (rb_IsCustYes.Checked || rb_IsCustNo.Checked)? rb_IsCustYes.Checked.ToString() : "NULL";
```

if you're inserting into the database later:

```
Cust.IsCust = (rb_IsCustYes.Checked || rb_IsCustNo.Checked)? Convert.ToInt16(rb_IsCustYes.Checked) : -1;

string IsCustValue = (IsCust == -1)? "NULL":IsCust.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you kscheik...But i want to insert a 1 or 0 or null value..So would your code do the same.

Comment: I am getting an error: Cannot implicitly convert type int to short using the above line of code..Thank you

Comment: I had Convert.ToInt32 where it should have been Convert.ToInt16 I guess. I've changed it now

Answer (score 1):

In your database you should set this field as bit to allow NULL values. However be careful of possible caveats.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2548/using-bit-columns-with-nulls-when-three-options-exist-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
Cust.IsCust = Convert.ToInt16(radiobutton1.Checked ? 1 : 0);
```

1 for checked 1st rdb
2  for checked 2nd rdb

Don't want second radiobutton conditions. because when you select 1st radio button , the second radio button is non selected. so,u can save 0

Edit:

```
string sss="NULL";

if(radiobutton1.Checked==true)
{
sss="1";
}
else if(radiobutton2.Checked==true)
{
sss="0";
}
```

Comment: Thank You all but when none of the radio buttons are checked i want to insert a null in the column..